# What is the nearest-neighbor distribution in this picture?

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability

Consider the following process:  sample $n$ points uniformly at random in the unit square, and for each point $i$, let $d_i$ be the distance from $i$ to its nearest neighbor.  Finally, let $z_i = d_i\sqrt{n}$.  My question is, what is known about the limiting distribution for the $z_i$'s as $n\to\infty$?  Here is a histogram for $n=10^6$:

[image: Nearest neighbor distribution]

I am most interested in the first-order behavior near $z=0$.  It *looks* like we have $f(z) \approx 0.14z$ or thereabouts but for all I know it might not even be linear.

Comment: What's the maximum, $\sqrt 2$? Looks like $>1.5$ in the figure

Comment: Square root of exponential?

Comment: If points are distributed according to a Poisson process with intensity 1, the probability that a point has no neighbor in distance $r$ is $e^{-\pi r^2}$.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen the maximum is actually $\sqrt{2n}$ because I scaled the nearest-neighbor distances by $\sqrt{n}$.  The distribution just has a small tail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n$ points are placed uniformly at random in the unit square, then the distribution is very close to a Poisson process with intensity $n$. Scaling the process by $\sqrt n$, it’s like a Poisson process with intensity 1. Conditioning a Poisson Process on the existence of a point at $x$, the remainder of the process is a Poisson process with the same intensity.

The probability that the nearest neighbor is more than $r$ away is the probability that a Poisson random variable with mean $\pi r^2$ takes the value 0, that is $e^{-\pi r^2}$. Differentiating, we see the density (which appears in your graph) is $2\pi re^{-\pi r^2}$.

The graph of this per wolfram alpha:
[image]

Comment: I see, is there a standard way to resolve the dependency between the samples?  In other words, I understand that if I choose a single point and look at the nearest neighbor distance, I get the function you wrote, but does the fact that I took the nearest-neighbor distances from all $n$ points change anything?

Comment: The dependency between points went away when I moved from having exactly $n$ points in the square to a Poisson process with intensity $n$ in the square. This is a very mild change. Things got even better when I moved to a Poisson process with intensity $n$ in the plane as that made the edge effects go away.

Comment: Sorry, this is kind of unfamiliar territory for me.  What I meant was, when I built my histogram, I sampled $n$ points and did a histogram of each of their nearest-neighbor distances.  I'm having difficulty resolving the fact that those $n$ distances are dependent, and I think they continue to be dependent even if we take the Poisson process approximation, no?

Comment: I see. Yes they are dependent in a single realization (=choice of points). For example if you take the closest pair of points, then the mutual distance is the minimum distance for both of them. But: since you are taking a large number of points, what you are really looking at is the distribution of the nearest neighbour distance from a single point. (This is essentially the strong law of large numbers: the number of points for which the nearest point is at distance in the range $[a/\sqrt n,b/\sqrt n]$ is $n$ times the probability that a single point has nearest point in that range).